# Why the text is not displayed on the label?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I see the text if I enlarge the window manually, so the text is there! (On the label) but if not enlarged the window I can not see, I see only a piece of the label

How can I fix it? Do I have to resize?

I've tried changing the font size, the size of the label and some other things and I could not even solve the problem.

This is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import time
import threading

def start():
    start_stop.config(text="QUIT", command=stop, image=photo2)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=progBar, args=())
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

def progBar():
    for i in xrange(300):
        if i < 50:
            lbl1.config(height=0, width=4, font=('times', 400, 'bold'),
                        text="AAAA!!")     
            lbl1.config(fg='black')

            if i % 5:
                lbl1.config(bg='white')
            else:
                lbl1.config(bg='red')

        if i == 50:
            lbl1.destroy()

        if i >= 200:
            s = ttk.Style()
            s.theme_use('clam')
            if i % 5:
                s.configure("red.Horizontal.TProgressbar", 
                            foreground='#205F8C', background='#205F8C')
            else:
                s.configure("red.Horizontal.TProgressbar", 
                            foreground='red', background='red')
            pbar_det.config(style="red.Horizontal.TProgressbar")

        pbar_det.step(0.33)
        master.update()
        # Busy-wait
        time.sleep(0.1)

    master.destroy()

def stop():
    master.destroy()

master = Tk()
photo1 = PhotoImage(file="Press1.gif")
photo2 = PhotoImage(file="Press2.gif")
ws = master.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = master.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen

width = ws
height = 120
x = ws-width # Window's coords
y = hs-height

start_stop = Button(master, text='START', command=start, image=photo1)
start_stop.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

pbar_det = ttk.Progressbar(master, orient="horizontal", length=ws-450,
                           mode="determinate")
pbar_det.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2, padx=2, sticky=E+W+N+S)

lbl1 = Label(master)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2, padx=2)
lbl2 = Label(master)
lbl2.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2, padx=2)

master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: what have you done to debug this? Have you verified that your calculations of width and height are what you expect? Also, are you intentionally putting two buttons plus two images in the same spot (row 0, column 1)?

Answer (score 0):

Try anchoring the text within the label to the left.

```
lbl1.config(anchor="nw") # nw = north-west = top left
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! but this does not solve the problem. The problem is exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

I see at least four problems in the code:

- you are forcing the size of the widget to a specific height when you call `master.geometry(...)`. This prevents the window from growing or shrinking to fit the internal widgets
- you are specifying a really huge font (400 points) which can't fit in the height you've picked. Because of the huge size of the font relative to the space you've given it (by explicitly setting the height of the window) what you see is the natural whitespace above the letters that is present in all fonts).
- you are putting two labels and one button on top of each other in the same row and column
- you are using threading. Tkinter isn't thread safe. Your code might work, but it might not.

If you remove the call to `master.geometry()`, the window will expand to fit the height of the text. Or, you can not make the font so huge.